# Solving Differentials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$xdx + ydy + \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} = 0$

The regular approach was isolating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dx}{dy}$ on one side and finding an appropriate substitution. But I am unable to find one. Another trouble is that the function is not homogeneous, so $y=vx$ fails here. Another question I have is, can there be a substitution for $x$ and $y$ with the same parameter, or does it require more information to be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$y=vx\implies dy=v\ dx+x\ dv$

$$\dfrac{x\ dy-y\ dx}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{x(vdx+x\ dv)-vx\ dx}{x^2+(vx)^2}=\dfrac{dv}{1+v^2}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{x\ dy-y\ dx}{x^2+y^2}=d(\arctan v)$$

Answer (score 0):

Following from previous answer: i.e. substituting $y=vx$ and substituting $ x^2+y^2=u$, the above equation can be rewritten as
$du/2 + dv/(1+v^2) = 0$.

And its solution will be $x^2+y^2 +2*arctan(y/x)=constant$.

Answer (score 0):

$$xdx + ydy + \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} = 0$$
$$xdx + ydy + \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})}=0$$
$$xdx + ydy + \frac{d(\frac{y}{x})}{(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})}=0$$
$$\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}{2}+\arctan(\frac yx)=c$$